# Changing Day and Month to DD and MM format in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

To give some context here, I have a dat file that I am trying to save as an xlsx on my Q drive.  I know that the majority of the code works (I've tested it), so I don't want to completely change it, but the formatting as I explain below is what I need help with. The following code is in workbook1 and it is referencing workbook2.  Cell D3 in workbook one is a date formula but unfortunately, the FileDay and FileMonth code will only pull in a single "d" or "m" when what I want is it to pull in days and months in the "dd" and "mm" format.  Since the code below is trying to find a file in this format: "yyyy_mm_dd"  but FileDay and FileMonth are only pulling in "d" and "m", it will only work during part of the year.  What is the piece of code that I am missing to pull in the correct formatting from cell D3?

```
Dim FName As String, FPath As String
Dim wkb1 As Workbook, wkb2 As Workbook

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook

FileDay = Day(Range("D3"))
FileMonth = Month(Range("D3"))
FileYear = Year(Range("D3"))


FPath = "Q:\MyFolder"
FName = "MyFile_" & FileYear & "_" & FileMonth & "_" & FileDay & ".xlsx"

Set wkb2 = Workbooks("MyFile_" & FileYear & "_" & FileMonth & "_" & FileDay 
& ".dat")
With wkb2
    .SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    .Close True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these variables are Strings, use the `Format$` function.

```
FileDay = Format$(Day(Range("D3")), "00")
FileMonth = Format$(Month(Range("D3")), "00")
FileYear = Format$(Year(Range("D3")), "0000")
```

Alternatively, do it all at once:

```
= Format$(Range("D3"), "YYYY_MM_DD")
```

Comment: Much appreciated @braX - that seemed to fix it!  Very good advice/help!  Thanks again.